Let $\ell_2=\{(x_n): \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^2\lt \infty\}$ and $A=\{(x_n):|x_n|\leq \frac 1n,n\in \Bbb N\}\subseteq\ell_2.$ Show that $A$ is closed.
Let $\ell_2=\{(x_n)\subseteq \Bbb C: \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^2\lt \infty\}$ and $A=\{(x_n):|x_n|\leq \frac 1n,n\in \Bbb N\}\subseteq X=\ell_2.$ Show that $A$ is closed.
My solution goes like this:
Let $x\in A'$, where $A'$ is the derived set of $A.$ This means, that $\exists$ a sequence $(x^{(k)})$ that converges to $x\in A',$ where $x^{(k)}=\{x_1^{(k)},x_2^{(k)},...\}$
So, for $\epsilon>0$ $\exists N\in\Bbb N$ such that $d(x^{(k)},y)<\epsilon,\forall k\geq N.$ Hence, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_i^{(k)}-x_i|^2\lt \epsilon,\forall k\geq N,\forall i\in \Bbb N.$
This implies, $|x_i^{(k)}-x_i|\lt\epsilon^{1/2}=\epsilon',\forall k\geq N,\forall i\in\Bbb N,$ which further implies $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_i^{(k)}=x_i,\forall i\in \Bbb N.$
Now, $|x_i^{(k)}|\leq \frac 1i,\forall k\in \Bbb N\implies |x_i^{(k)}|\leq \frac 1i,\forall k\in\Bbb N\implies \lim_{k\to\infty}|x_i^{(k)}|=|x_i|\leq \frac 1i,\forall i\in \Bbb N\implies x\in A.$ Thus, $A$ is closed.

Can the above solution be improved? Any suggestions on how make the above proof more readable will be highly appreciated. I want to specifically improve the proof writing in order to make the arguments more presentable. Lastly, if there is any mistake with my proof, please feel free to point it out.

You are saying 'equivalent to' in place of 'implies' at one place. Otherwise, your proof is fine.

@geetha290krm Thanks for pointing out the error! I have edited it. Is the solution all correct now?

Your proof is fine, although there is a reasoning avoiding sequences of elements in $\ell^2.$ Namely, let $\varphi_n(x)=x_n.$ Then $\varphi_n$ is a bounded linear functional on $\ell^2,$ as $$|\varphi(x)|=|x_n|\le \|x\|$$ Therefore the sets $$A_n=\{x\in \ell^2\,:\, |\varphi_n(x)|\le n^{-1}\}$$  are closed. As $A=\bigcap A_n,$ then $A$ is closed as well.
The coefficients $1/n$ can be replaced by any nonnegative numbers $a_n$ not necessarily square summable.

It's easier to prove that the complement is open. So suppose $(x_n)\in A^c$, the complement of $A$ (you already used $A'$). Then there exists $k$ such that $|x_k|>1/k$.
But now if $(y_n)$ is any sequence with $\sum|x_n-y_n|^2<(|x_n|-1/k)^2$, we must have $|y_k-x_k|<|x_k|-1/k$. So $|y_k|>1/k$, which means $(y_n)\in A^c$. Thus there is an open ball around $(x_n)$ that is contained in $A^c$, hence $A^c$ is an open set.
